# Undefined variable error when running macro in ImageJ

Tags: imagej, fiji, imagej-macro

I am new to ImageJ macros and I want to use a macro in Fiji. The code for the macro is from this [source](https://gist.github.com/mutterer/7901a5444920e4da568adeafb58338f1/revisions).

```
macro "MultiRoiMove Tool - C00cT0f16M" {
  if (RoiManager.selected<2) exit(); 
  indexes=split(call("ij.plugin.frame.RoiManager.getIndexesAsString"));
  roiManager("Combine");
  getCursorLoc(x, y, z, modifiers);
  Roi.getBounds(x0, y0, width, height);
  while(modifiers&16>0) {
    getCursorLoc(x1, y1, z, modifiers);
    Roi.move(x0+x1-x, y0+y1-y);
  }
  roiManager("select", indexes);
  roiManager("translate", x1-x, y1-y);
}
```

I have downloaded the code and saved it as a text file. I have then run the macro through going to Plugins > Macros > Run. The version of ImageJ I am using is 1.53j.

However, when I run the macro, I am getting the following error:

[image]

I have seen online on the ImageJ [forum](https://forum.image.sc/t/moving-two-rois-simultaneously-while-keeping-their-relative-position/50108) that this macro works for other people. I have done some debugging and know that I am getting the error because the code does not go into the while loop when I run the macro, so there isn't a value for `x1` returned by the `getCursorLoc` function.

But I am not how to get the code to go into the while loop. Does anyone know if I have to click something specific before running the macro? It seems to me that the code will go into the while loop when a mouse modifier event occurs (as the modifiers parameter returned by the getCursorLoc function are the mouse event modifier flags). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the ROIs in the ROI Manager that you'd like to move. You can click the first one and then cmd + click (on Mac) to add additional ROIs. The macro will then move those ROIs but not any that are unselected.

The `modifiers` part of the code receives which mouse buttons are being pressed and if the use left-clicks (16) and drags this defines a rectangle which is then used to move the ROIs.

You should choose Plugins > Macros > Install to get the tool added to the toolbar.